# Sharing a delegate property between methods

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, swagger, extension-methods

I'm working with the type `Action<T1>` in my own extension method, although I'd like to build up a property within the delegate and then pass that delegate property to another method which will add properties as well.

An example of this would be if I was to write my own extension methods for adding swagger to an `IServiceCollection`. Let's say there's a `OperationFilter` and a `DocumentFilter` and a lot of other standard properties that I'm setting on the `SwaggerGenOptions`, so I've taken the decision to create my own NuGet package with a default `IServiceCollection` extension to do all this across all my services.

I would like something similar to the following (or combining the delegate properties of those past in and those being set in this method in the `AddSwaggerGen` call):

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCommonSwaggerGen(this IServiceCollection services, Action<SwaggerGenOptions> options)
{
    // Somehow I'd like to do this:
    options.OperationFilter<MyOperationFilter>();
    options.DocumentFilter<MyDocumentFilter>();

    options.OrderActionsBy(a => a.RelativePath);
    options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

    // Then I can just pass it in to AddSwaggerGen
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options);

    return services;
}
```

Then in each application, I'd like to do something like:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo() { Title = "Micro Service 1 Api v1.0", Version = "v1.0" });

    // Also set other option properties customised to each service
});
```

What would be the best way of achieving this or is it just not achievable in this way?

My next option was going to be pass in the `SwaggerGenOptions` and investigate using that in the Action, but then I would probably need something like `Automapper` to map all the properties across which would be irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression you are trying to do something like this

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCommonSwaggerGen(
    this IServiceCollection services, Action<SwaggerGenOptions> configure == null) {

    services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
        //Common
        options.OperationFilter<SwaggerRemoveVersionFromParameter>();
        options.DocumentFilter<SwaggerReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPath>();
        options.OrderActionsBy(a => a.RelativePath);
        options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        //additional options configuration
        configure?.Invoke(options);
    });

    return services;
}
```

Then in each application, do something like:

```
services.AddCommonSwaggerGen(options => {
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo() { Title = "Micro Service 1 Api v1.0", Version = "v1.0" });

    // Also set other option properties customized to each service
});
```

Or

```
services.AddCommonSwaggerGen();
```